# What would be an efficient way to find the Common words in 3 Files in Java?

Tags: java, string, file

What I am planning to do is basically :

1. Read the first file word by word and store the words in a Set(SetA).
2. Read the second file and check if the first Set(SetA) contains the word, if it does then store it in the second set(SetB). Now SetB contains the common words in first and Second file.
3. Similarly we will read the third file and check if SetB contains the word and store the words in SetC.

So if you have any suggestions or any problems in my approach. Please Suggest.

Comment: An optimization would be to start with the smallest file, or ideally with the file containing the smallest amount of unique words. For huge files, storing all the words in sets could cause out of memory issues.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Agreed. I thought about it and I feel if we have multiple files, we cannot just keep increasing the number of Sets.
We can achieve this using only two Sets - One Which contains the Common words and Other which contains the Unique words of the current file we are iterating. This way we will have only two sets.

Comment: So to process the next file you need to store all its words in a temporary set. Then determine the intersection of the commonWords set and the temporary set (the intersection contains only the words that occur in both sets). The result of this is the new commonWords set and the temporary set can be discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the intersection of two sets using [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        List<String> file1 = Arrays.asList("aap", "noot", "aap", "wim", "vuur", "noot", "wim");
        List<String> file2 = Arrays.asList("aap", "noot", "mies", "aap", "zus", "jet", "aap", "wim", "vuur");
        List<String> file3 = Arrays.asList("noot", "mies", "wim", "vuur");

        System.out.println(getCommonWords(file1, file2, file3));
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private final Set<String> getCommonWords(List<String>... files) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        // possible optimization sort files by ascending size
        Iterator<List<String>> it = Arrays.asList(files).iterator();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            result.addAll(it.next());
        }
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(it.next());
            result.retainAll(words);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214519/java-intersection-of-multiple-collections-using-stream-lambdas) which shows the same solution I gave above, and also ways to do it with Java 8 Streams.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The approach seems sound. May I suggest using [Regex](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to possibly save your time coding. One other concern would be to make sure to not store *every* word, but instead to store only *unique* words in your set.

Comment: Well Set takes cares of the uniqueness by itself. Its the property of a set to store unique objects

Comment: My apologies, for some reason I thought you were using a custom implementation.

Comment: How regexp will help?

Comment: After generating the unique list you can use Regex to perform matches to see if the words are contained in the file. Just standard pattern matching. Unless Regex no longer has the capability. He could also just put it in a for loop or use another function to help parse the data.